# Correcting for reliability scores for Hedges g

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, reliability, bias-correction

I've received a revise and resubmit on my meta-analysis investigating the effects of a positive psychology intervention on depression and anxiety symptoms. I used Hedges' *g* as the effect size within a random effects model (using the DerSimonian & Laird estimator of heterogeneity). The effect size estimates the difference between the intervention and a control group. I've received feedback from a reviewer that I'm not sure how to address. The feedback is as follows:

"Due to the imperfect reliability of the outcome variable, the average observed effect size is an underestimate of the real effect size; simultaneously, the observed variance contains variance that can be attributed to the imperfect reliability. So, I would like to see the estimates of the real (corrected) effect sizes, the real (corrected) standard error, and the real (corrected) 95% CI."

How does one correct for reliability in estimating the effect size, standard error, and 95% CI for Hedges' *g*?

Comment: You need to investigate the Hunter-Schmidt method. If you use R it is implemented in the psychmeta package available from CRAN. I am not expert enough in the method to make this an answer which is why it is just a comment.

Comment: Thank you, mdewey. Do you know of any references to learn this method? And can it be applied to Hedges' g?